# Can it be that I did try that ice cream, but have not tried it?

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

English is not my first language, but I reached fluency, and the language barrier only hinders me rarely. One such case is with the choice of either past indefinite or present perfect tense.

For example, suppose there is a new sort of ice cream in town. Can it be that I did try that ice cream, but have not tried it? One interpretation I can give is that I made an effort, but did not succeed. *("Have not succeeded"?)* Like, I ate one, but the taste eluded me. Would such interpretation be correct? If not, can another be offered?

Comment: Perhaps better answers will be given at ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: That would not be a normal interpretation.

Comment: Your sentence is a contradiction. You could say "I did try it, but I didn't like it" OR "I have tried it, but..."

Comment: Maybe you’re a judge who has overseen a court case with the ice-cream but have not actually tasted it.

Comment: ... or tasted but haven’t judged it yet.

Comment: @Lawrence - But then you’d have to recuse yourself. :-)

Comment: @Jim on the contrary, tasting is essential to judging - at least for judging food. :)

Comment: @Lawrence -  Ha!

Answer (score 0):

No. That doesn't make sense.  But you could say you tried to try the ice cream, but since it fell to the ground before you could get it into your mouth, you have not tried it. As far as the taste eluding you, well that does not negate the fact that you tried the ice cream.

Answer (score -1):

My ice cream cone  was melted so I licked the dripped  Carmel running down my finger.